# How do I create a one-step form?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to create a one-step form where the only thing you need to do is click one of these SVGs? Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

What I would like to achieve is at the bottom of a page, there will be a `<h1>Did you find this helpful?</h1>` tag followed by these SVGs, which, when clicked, will send an email to an email address, the subject of the email being changed depending on which one the user clicked on followed by the URL that they clicked the SVG on.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your goal? You already mentioned php in the tags. Its up to what you want to do.

Comment: Please Explain what you want... I think this is not PHP stuff.

Comment: `onclick` maybe? I don't know, it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

add link to them like:

```
<a href="someurl?smile=1">first svg</a>
<a href="someurl?smile=2">second svg</a>
<a href="someurl?smile=3">third svg</a>
```

If you want to post parameters in that case you'll need to use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Use onkeypress attribute to activate a function when clicked on.

```
function submitform(mood) {
    window.location.href = "http://foo.com/formsubmit?mood=" + mood;
}

<img src="Happy.jpg" onkeypress="submitform("happy")">
<img src="No_Expression.jpg" onkeypress="submitform("None")">
<img src="Sad.jpg" onkeypress="submitform("Sad")">
```